# Parsing a set of range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wrote a simple code to find the intersection between two set of ranges and print the intersection. Now i am trying to write the result to a file. but i get an error saying write() argument must be str not set.

```
 import numpy 
# initialize A and B
filename = "set.txt"
f = open("set.txt", "w")
x = numpy.arange(4000, 5000, 1)

y = numpy.arange(3500, 5500, 1)
#x.intersection(y)

#print (set(x).intersection(y))

 f.write(set(x).intersection(y))
 f.close()
```

it works with print but i include the write it give that error

Comment: Unable to reproduce on `python3.7` or on `python2.7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command must be 'str' type:

```
f.write(str(set(x).intersection(y)))
```